# Clustering of dataset using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

I have a repeated string data set as below.

> [Building Repairs & Maintenance,Books-CDs-Audio-Video,Stationery,Other
>   Services,Building Repairs & Maintenance]

I want to cluster the same value in one cluster using the above data set.
The output should be

> [Building Repairs & Maintenance,Building Repairs &
>   Maintenance,...][Other Services,Other Services,...]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure what you want exactly and how does it relates to machine learning. But you can achieve the above result easily in python without the use of machine learning or kmeans clustering.

Here is the sample code for that:

```
import collections
data = ["Building Repairs & Maintenance","Books-CDs-Audio-Video","Stationery","Other Services","Building Repairs & Maintenance"]
duplicate_count = collections.Counter(data)
for key in duplicate_count:
    print [key]*count[key]
```

It would be great if you can elaborate your problem a bit more and how does it relate to machine learning.

### Edit #1:

Are you talking about finding similar text in the list, for example
[Books-Audio-CD, Audio, Textbook, Building Repair and Maintenance, Repair and Maintenance, Repairing]

gives the following output

[Books-Audio-CD, Audio, Textbook]
[Building Repair and Maintenance, Apartment Services, Repairing]

This is where it would be more suitable to use machine learning and clustering as the strings in this situation are not an exact match but are related to each other in context and meaning.

### Edit #2:

For Bag of words approach, you can take a guide from this code. However this is just a basic implementation I did just now and it needs to be modified for adding necessary features like stemming, stop word removal and tfidf in place of the simple bag of words representation to make it more accurate.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer as _Vect
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

simple_vectorizer = _Vect(min_df=1)
train_fit = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)

#Sample Initialization of K-means. Assuming number of clusters to be 2.
km = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init='random', n_init=1)
km.fit(train_fit)
print km.labels_
```

### Edit #3

Simple Moving Average Implementation based on the public dataset. For this, I saved the values in a temporary file name so.csv.

First of all, looking at your data I don't think that you need to use clustering technique for categories at all, as all the specific categories are exactly the same. You can easily just filter out or use grouping to get rows from same category.

Secondly as we are not concerned with clustering any more there is no specific need of weighted average for different strings.

Although this method is giving predicted values for each category. I think a more robust method like arima would be much better suited in your case as much of your data is clearly reflecting a strong hint of trends and seasonality

All these suggestions are purely based on the public dataset you provided.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

so = pd.read_csv('so.csv',parse_dates = ['Date'])

for category in list(set(so['Category'])):
    filtered = so.loc[so['Category'] == category].sort_values(by='Date').set_index('Date')
    ma = filtered.tail(3)['Amount'].mean()
    print "Category:",category,"\t\nNext Predicted Amount(Moving Average Value [Past 3 Months]) :",ma,"\n"


    # To plot the values you can uncomment the below given code.
    # y = list(filtered['Amount'])
    # y.extend([ma])
    # x = np.array(range(len(y)))
    # plt.plot(x, y)
    # plt.show()
```

Comment: I want to predict the expenditure of a particular customer(future one month) using the data set categories of transaction and amount(previous 3 months).

Comment: Thanks you rishabh malhotra for your quick response

Comment: yes i want the output as [Books-Audio-CD, Audio, Textbook] [Building Repair and Maintenance, Apartment Services, Repairing]

Comment: Alright so for that you need to elaborate on what kind of data set do you have. By that I mean do you have just these category labels or there is some sort of textual description associated with each of them.

Assuming that these are only labels, I would say you basically have two broad options based on the level of complexity you want to introduce. The first option is to use the bag of words approach and second is to use the word embedding approach. Both of them are basically just giving your text strings a numerical representation which you can feed to your clustering algorithms.

Comment: category=["Building Repairs & Maintenance","Books-CDs-Audio-Video","Stationery","Other Services","Building Repairs & Maintenance",.......]

Comment: By using this data i have to predict the next month amount expenditure of each category.

Comment: Alright, so one super basic way of doing this is you can cluster similar categories using the bag of words approach. Then calculate the weighted average their every month's amounts and apply moving averages on those values.

One way for calculating the weighted average you can factor in how many elements does the category has in it. as more the number of individual elements in a category, the more support that category provides to the cluster value.

Comment: Thank you rishabh malhotra.But how to calculate weighted average of every month?

Comment: according to the values in your above comment. If I want to calculate the weighted averages and I assume that the 1st category of "Building Repairs and maintenance" has 6 items linked to it and 2nd category of "Building Repairs and maintenance" have only 2 items linked to it then

Weighted average would be (6/8 * (2398)) + (2/8 * (764)) = 1989.5
. 
I am just calculating the weights simply by (number of items in specific category /number of total items in all categories in a cluster). You can use another criterion as well based on your business logic.

Comment: How to apply the averages  on those values?

Comment: I have applied bag of words approach to my data set

Comment: I got output as {'building': 5, 'repairs': 36, 'maintenance': 24, 'books': 4, 'cds': 8, 'audio': 3, 'video': 49, 'stationery': 40, 'other': 30, 'services': 38, 'cleaning': 10, 'and': 2, 'domestic': 12, 'material': 25, 'e19': 13, 'learning': 23, 'resources': 37, 'education': 15, 'cfr': 9, 'administrative': 0, 'occupation': 28, 'equipment': 17, 'materials': 26, 'purcha': 35, 'transfer': 47, 'payments': 32, 'to': 45, 'soc': 39, 'food': 20, 'costs': 11, 'e25': 14, 'catering': 7, '}

Comment: Hi rakesh, you can refer to edit #2 in my answer for the bag of words approach basic implementation. Once you are able to create clusters using this, then you can use the weighted average method to calculate the values.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, if the answer has helped you can you please accept it by marking on the correct symbol next to it. Thanks

Comment: By using the code in edit#2 i got output as [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
 ]

Comment: What i have to do next to get weighted average?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I think you didnt change the number of clusters, please replace the n_clusters = 2 with the number of categories your data have. For example if you have 3 categories namely building repair, stationary and books than make n_cluster= 3

Comment: i have changed n_clusters=22

Comment: I got output as [16 16  4  2  4  4  8  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5 11 11 11 11 11 10 10 14 14
 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  2
  2  2  2 12 12 12 12  1  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  8  8  8  8  8  8  5
  5  5  0  0 12 12 12 12  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6 19 19  2  8  8  8  6  3  7
 12  1  4  8  8 17 17 17 17  8  5  6  5  5 12  8 12  7  7  7  6  6 10 20 16
 16 16 12 12 12 12 12  6  8  8  8  7 13 12  7  3 15  5  6  6  6  4  6  1  7
  3 12  4  3  3  3  9  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  1 20  8
 20  7  8  1  3 12  7 10 10  1  1 12 12 12 ]

Comment: I have 22 categories.How to calculate the weighted average using above comment result?

Comment: Can you get the number of elements in each category? For example, can you get number elements associated with the category which is the first category of cluster 16?

Comment: Can you get the number of elements in each string? For example, can you get number elements associated with the string which is the first category of cluster 16? 

If you can then let's suppose there are 10 strings which all fall in cluster 16. You multiply amount of each string with (number of elements associated with that string/number of total elements in associated with all strings in cluster 16)

Comment: I used the below comment code to get the above comment output

Comment: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(category)
true_k = 22
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k)
a=model.fit(X)
print(a.labels_)

Comment: I am not getting what to do next

Comment: If it's alright, Can you send me your problem data sample? I can help you better that way. or Just send me some dummy data in the exact format you are using. That would be fine as well.

Comment: You can see the dataset using the url-https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1juejCJw8Wrnj5f_Xx3FXj6X4XLBOefbrUzE4Ndv7Gkk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have requested for the access.

Comment: Use this url.Its public...https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ypVo-jpvOqfWtP--o0WplfEg20I5eAfP8ZOXYx9Dlw8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to predict the next month total expenditure of each category

Comment: Hi Rakesh you can see edit #3 for implmentation of simple moving average of next month total expenditure.

Comment: Thanks you so much rishabh malhotra

Comment: Please upvote the answer if you found it useful. Thanks

Comment: Okai rishabh malhotra

Comment: How to get the last date of each category?

Comment: My dataset has Education CFR Administrative S,Education CFR Other Occupation categories.I want to cluster it has education and predict the expense amount.